# Как сделать grid в frontend?

Tags: php, javascript, magento

Возможно ли в frontend magegento 1 сделать такую таблицу как в админке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Или лучше сделать в phtml файле используя js библиотеку ?**

Нужен совет, рекомендация. Или подсказка как реализовать (желательнее) стандартный grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Cоздавать отдельную `фабрику` - `factory` для модуля работающего на фронтэнде. Рэндэр на phtml, тогда получиться что то вроде такого грид.
2. Можно просто выдавать доступы к гриду продуктов, и созданию продуктов к админке, при создание аккуанта,и не пилить пол админки на фронте. А просто добавить какой то атрибут для юзера и фильтроватть по нему.

И так разберём подробнее первый случайна псевдо php языке (не буду писать полностью функционал просто покажу логику)

создаём абстрактный класс в директории `Block` нашего модуля, для примера модуль будет `Test_Frontgreed` и по анологии реализуем его с adminhtml

file Block/Abstract.php

```
abstract class Test_Frontend_Block_Abstract extends Core_Block_Template 
{
   private $_collection = null;
   private $_columns = array();

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->setTemplate('your/greed.phtml');
   }

   protected function _prepareCollection()
   {
      if($collection = $this->getData('collection') {
          // логика фильтрации коллекции
          $collection->load();
          return $collection;
      }
   }

   public function getCollection() 
   {
     if(is_null($this->_collection)) {
         $this->_collection = $this->_prepareCollection();
     }

     return $this->_collection;
   }

   abstract public function prepareGrid(); //prepare grid

   protected function _addColumn($type,$key,$options) 
   {
      $this->_columns[$key] = array(
          'type' => $type;
          'options' => $options;
      );  
   }

   public function getCollumn() {
       if(count($this->_columns) == 0) {
           $this->prepareGrid();
       } 
       return $this->_columns;
   } 

}
```

реализовывем базовый класс грида расширенный от предыдущего

```
class Test_Frontend_Block_Product extends Test_Frontend_Block 
{
   protected function _prepareCollection()
   {
       $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
       $this->setCollection();
       parent:_prepareCollection();
   }

   public function prepareGrid()
   {
      $this->_addColumn('text','entity_id',array('custom_options' => 'custom'));
   }
}
```

ну и последние реализвать сам шаблон

```
<?php foreach($this->getCollection() as $_product): ?>
<tr>
  <?php foreach($this->getCollumn() as $_key => $_collumn): ?>
     <td><?php echo $_product->getData($_key) ?> </td>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Ну вот вот такой простой пример реализации фабрики, хотя второй вариант должен быть предпочтительней.